# First MPart with first part of input file and Second MPart with second part of input file

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

Is this possible to make editor which contains of two parts, each of which would display its own part of the input file?

Comment: You could have some sort of manager class that the code in the two parts communicate with to coordinate access - but all that is down to you to code.